# virtuemart url problem

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Everything worked correct, but now after client modification, there another params added to url

It was like

http://sitename/pagename?page=shop.browse&category_id=7

and when I click on it it looks like:

http://sitename/index.php?page=shop.browse&category_id=7&redirected=1&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=71

Any ideas?

thanks, Ahmed.

Comment: What is wrong with the 2nd url?

Comment: I think, You are using any SEF component or language based component.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a link to a Virtuemart menu item. Someone probably did something with a menu item, added one or the sort. itemid represents the menu item id.